# Convert JSONArray to Map using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, hashmap

In our legacy code, we are sending request body in a form of a `HashMap`, something I cannot change because other applications may be affected.

Sample Hashmap value = `{name=name1, age=age1}`

However I have problem on using `HashMap` if there are multiple JSON objects in my request, for example

```java
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

for (Person person: Persons) {
    map.put("name", "name1");
    map.put("age", "age1");
}
```

If there are 2 or more people, only the last person's name and age will be put in the `Map`, because the first person's name and age are overridden because they have the same key ("name" and "age").

My desired map value was `[{name=name1, age=age1}, {name=name2, age=age2}]`, but I only got `{name=name2, age=age2}`

What I did is, in every loop, I put it in `JSONArray`:

```java
JSONArray jsonArray = new jsonArray();

for (Person person: Persons) {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("name", "name1");
    map.put("age", "age1");
    jsonArray.put(map);
}
```

So when I print `JSONArray`, it is:

```
[{"name":"name1", "age":"age1"}, {"name":"name2", "age":"age2"}]
```

But again, I need to transform this into `HashMap` so I can pass it as parameter to `oursendRequest()` method.

I tried to use the `ObjectMapper` in Jackson, but it didn't work.

Is this possible, and how?

Comment: Your example is incomplete, and please stick to proper naming conventions for Java.

Comment: May I know what is incomplete in my example?Thanks

Comment: What is an _actual_ example of the JSON input? Like, where are there multiples? Also, if you are using the standard Collections, use `Map` as your type for the `HashMap` as this is more standard practice. It is just one of the many implementations, so the implementation does not matter in this case. Lastly, if two people do have the same name, then of course one will be overridden. That is how a map works.

Comment: The sample json input is the value of jsonArray object I stated above. I want that value of jsonArray to be transformed into Map<String, Object> map, because I will pass the map in my request method. My ultimate goal is to come up with map object with similar value of the jsonArray.

Comment: What does an example of `List<Person>` look like? Is this what you start with? Do you get this back as JSON? Why would you map it to `JSONArray` and not `List<Person>`? Why do you even need the JSON library, if you already have a POJO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would deserialize the JSON into a `List` of people first. After that, I would group them by name.

### Main.java

```java
package q61078696;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            List<Person> people = loadJSON("q61078696/people.json", Person.class);
            Map<String, List<Person>> groupedByName = people.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName));
            System.out.println(groupedByName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String loadJSON(String resourceName) {
        InputStream is = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
        String jsonString = null;
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())) {
            jsonString = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        }
        return jsonString;
    }

    public static <E> List<E> loadJSON(String resourceName, Class<E> clazz) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonString = loadJSON(resourceName);
        CollectionType typeReference = TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class, clazz);
        return mapper.readValue(jsonString, typeReference);
    }
}
```

### Output

```
{Tom=[{ "name": "Tom", "age": 28 }], Bob=[{ "name": "Bob", "age": 42 }, { "name": "Bob", "age": 21 }], Mary=[{ "name": "Mary", "age": 35 }]}
```

### Person.java

```java
package q61078696;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person() {
        this(null, 0);
    }

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{ \"name\": \"%s\", \"age\": %d }", this.name, this.age);
    }
}
```

### people.json

```
[
  { "name" : "Bob",  "age" : 42 },
  { "name" : "Bob",  "age" : 21 },
  { "name" : "Mary", "age" : 35 },
  { "name" : "Tom",  "age" : 28 }
]
```

### Dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

### Additional Info

If you want to map by name and avoid grouping (ignoring dupes).

This will throw an `IllegalStateException`, because there are duplicate keys, to avoid this, you will need to access the map.

```java
Map<String, Person> groupedByName = people.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getName, Function.identity()));
```

You can avoid this by specifying a `mergeFunction`

```java
Map<String, Person> groupedByName = people.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Person::getName,     // keyMapper
        Function.identity(), // valueMapper
        (o1, o2) -> o1,      // mergeFunction (keep the first occurrence)
        TreeMap::new)        // mapSupplier
    );
```

You can also specify a `supplier` in the 4th parameter. I chose a `TreeMap` to keep the name keys in order.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-

Comment: Can we wak the groupByName Map<String, Object>? and value should be the map equivalent of the people.json and not grouped by name.

Comment: @drn Then what do you want to group by then? Maps require keys; what is your key?